# Why is my lemon verbena showing signs of distress?

Tags: plant-health, herbs, container-gardening

I acquired a lemon verbena earlier in the year. I have been cutting sprigs for culinary purposes. In recent weeks, it has begun to look sad, i.e. wilting leaves, appearing spindly. Is this to be expected at this time of year or am I not tending it properly? It is protected from the wind in partial shade, and lives in a sizable terracotta pot.

[image]

Comment: How big was the plant when you planted it in this pot?  Is there a saucer beneath and tell us how and why you water.  Looks to me like over watering.  I could be wrong...more pictures and more about your methods with this plant!!  And is it still in partial shade?  How long has this plant been growing in this pot?  Lemon verbena would LOVE full sun if properly hardened and that would also help remove some of the water.  Please post a picture of your entire plant and tell us how you water, fertilize.  I think too much water...

Comment: I shall take more photos in the morning. Thank you so much for responding, Julie

Comment: Hey Julie, I enlarged the picture you sent and I see some signs of possible spider mite.  Can you see any webbing at all?  And what kind of soil did you use?  Did you use potting soil or garden soil?  Looking forward to more pictures (get some close ups if you are able).

Comment: please send another picture or replace this picture with a close up of those leaves.  It most certainly is a bit stressed but lemon verbena is TOUGH.  Certainly in the category with weeds it is so tough.  Is this plant the ONLY plant in your pot?  Looks like you've used potting soil from a bag, is that correct?  Did you put rocks or gravel at the bottom above the hole in the pot?  Depending on your answers, this guy could use being chopped down to 6-8".  What are you using for fertilizer? How often?  Please tell us about your zone!  I see signs of sucking insects...close ups, please!

Answer (score 1):

If your plant is looking poorly in the summer, there are a few things to look at. They are a heavy feeder, unlike most herbs, and thrive off of a high nitrogen fertilizer. In a container, I would recommend feeding regularly, due to potting medium leaching.

Also water the plant very well, keeping the soil moist. Every time the top inch or so of soil dries out, it's time to water gain. And the mix needs to drain well. Make sure that water can not sit in the bottom of the planter. If it's sitting in a deep saucer that collects water, that will harm the plant. They don't like wet feet.

Lemon verbena drops leaves at about 45 degrees Fahrenheit, and goes dormant. You can overwinter it outdoors in USDA Hardiness zones 8 and up. In colder areas, wait until the plant goes dormant, and overwinter indoors, in a cool, dimly lit area.

When harvesting, cut long stems, back to a healthy branch, or set of leaves. Keep the center thinned out, and long growth cut back. Proper and frequent harvesting promotes, bushier, healthy new growth.

Aside from that, keep an eye out for pests of any kind, and treat appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell from your picture, there seems to be white spots on some leaves which can be a sign of a fungus or aphids. Also, verbena will shed it's leaves when the temp gets colder, it can seem quite poor that starts to happen.

Comment: Again, I am so grateful for the advice of experts. I am an eager learner.